# Displaying a PDF string passed from server in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, http, pdf, servlets

I am trying to display a PDF that has been written to a HTTPServletResponse in a new window via JavaScript.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"action=previewPDF"})
public void view(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {

SessionInfo sessionInfo = (SessionInfo) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(SessionInfo.SESSION_INFO_REQUEST_KEY);

String fileDestination = "C:/test.pdf";
File f = new File(fileDestination);
if (f.isFile()) {
  httpServletResponse.reset();
  httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
  httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+fileDestination+";");
  FileUtils.copyFile(f, httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
  httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

}

In the javascript:

```
success : function(result) {
            alert("Success");
            console.log(result);
            window.open("data:application/pdf;base64" + escape(result.responseText));
        }
```

It goes into the success function but tries to display the link in a new tab but I get an error saying the site cannot be reached.

The link appears like :

```
data:application/pdf;base64%25PDF-1.3%0A%25%uFFFD%uC3E2%0A30%200%20obj%0A%3C%3C/Length%2031%200%20R/Filter%20/FlateDecode%3E%3E%0Astream%0Ax%uFFFD%uF......
```

Would anyone be able to suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need a `,` after `base64` to make that into a valid data URI. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: Hi @JoeClay, I have added the "," but still the same result unfortunately

Comment: Actually, ignore the comment I just posted/deleted, I don't think it was correct. I'm not sure what your issue is, hopefully someone else will chip in with an answer!